# Python for processing big data "filter the timestamp logs by hours"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

everyone I' like to processing over 5GB of .CSV format logs, the internal structure below.

```
 widget_id,device_type,timestamp
    3db953e172f313e674374e71730b0c746bea97be,desktop,2017-01-10T00:10:25.948Z
    714e7cd6ecc029152b1a9d1e8620d911870a932a,mobile,2017-01-10T01:10:50.134Z
    e83ce32fa2b74ad65091b66e2cab94b684073f8c,mobile,2017-01-10T02:10:29.137Z
    fee4ef0a02be0648d3fa829e4a0b1a1b484b49d9,mobile,2017-01-10T03:10:30.249Z
    02ccc3e5f0f53e4e2f02e08c4b8baa8d3167ae0f,mobile,2017-01-10T04:10:53.177Z
    97cc7010b2ff9a9d6eefc94856cb6394c81c4d47,desktop,2017-01-10T05:10:53.246Z
    bccb35fcb9befbc8fb99a373e8e939cd20273774,desktop,2017-01-10T06:10:31.137Z
```

Firstly, I like to sort the events based on the timestamp, because the all logs is without timestamp order. Here is my code I used  `for item in sorted(readCSV, key=lambda asd: asd[2], reverse=False):`  and I also need to calculate the 24 hours per hours events , I'm trying to use Dict structure use the Key for store 1-24 hours, and each key(hours) mapping Values for store the events numbers, but here I used `if 'T01' in item[2]: until if 'T24' in item[2]:`  I need 24 if statement, does anyone have smart method for solve this?

```
def csv_reader():
    with open('/Users/mac/Downloads/data.csv') as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        HashMap={}
        counter=0
        for item in sorted(readCSV, key=lambda asd: asd[2], reverse=False):
          if 'T01' in item[2]:
              counter = counter + 1
              HashMap['T01']=counter
        for key in HashMap.values():
            print key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can extract the key for your HashMap using (assuming the format is always the same):

```
key = item[2][10:13]
```

Comment: hi snow, i was wonder what the means of [10:13] does means 10:00 to 13:00 ??

Comment: It's called "slicing", it means characters of `item[2]` from position 10 (included) to 13 (excluded). In this case, it's TXX (XX is 00 to 24 as you mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with [ApacheSpark](http://spark.apache.org/)? It's a big data processing platform that I have personally used to process large amounts of CSV data (in my case it was stock data) in a very fast and scalable way. It has builtin CSV reading capabilities so all you need is a few function calls and you can perform operations on your data. Well documented as well.

Comment: Hi Vedranh13, Thanks for your advice, but in this case is mandatory to use the Python script.